# Возможно ли перегрузить метод Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net

Возможно ли перегрузить метод `Console.WriteLine` ?

Пример `Console.WriteLine("str", ConsoleColor.Green);`

Интересует именно перегрузка в такой форме. Создавать другой класс и вызывать из другого объекта - не вариант.

Comment: Напишите свой собственный метод расширения.

Comment: Попробуйте Console.SetOut https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ну вам обязательно писать именно `Console.WriteLine`? Вы можете создать свой класс с любым названием и в нем реализовать метод, который: 1. Меняет цвет на полученный в параметре; 2. Выводит строку; 3. Возвращает цвет. Метод расширения в этом случае не получится, т.к. `Console` - статический класс

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655536/is-it-possible-to-write-extension-methods-for-console

Comment: @therainycat а причем тут замена стандартного потока для вывода?

Comment: @rdorn если рассматривать вопрос автора как "как перегрузить стандартный статический метод", то ни при чем. Я лишь предположил, что автору это необходимо для того, чтобы отловить весь вывод в консоль, не переписывая везде Console.WriteLine, и предложил посмотреть на официальное, вполне обьективное решение задачи. Заменять (если это возможно) статический метод, при чем стандартный, из Console - мне что-то подсказывает, что цель была не в этом. Но я не уверен, какую цель преследует автор, потому и написал комментарий, а не ответ :)

Comment: В общем, нет. Можете посмотреть альтернативы здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class